# Insert multiple rows using for loop laravel

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "0" of relation
>   "payments" does not exist\n LINE 1: insert into "payments" ("0", "1",
>   "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "...\n

[image]

```
    $payments = [];
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 12; $x++) {
      $payments[] = new Payments([
          'id' => Uuid::generate()->string,
          'number_of_months' => $request->number_of_months,
          'status' =>  $request->status,
          'date_of_expire' => $request->date_of_expire,
          'amount' => $request->amount,
          'unpaid_amount' =>  $request->unpaid_amount,
          'user_id' => $request->user_id,
          'date_of_payment' => $date->addMonths(1),
      ]);
    }

   DB::table('payments')->insert($payments);
```

Model

```
  public $incrementing = false;


  protected $fillable = [
      'id',
      'number_of_months',
      'date_of_payment',
      'date_of_expire',
      'amount',
      'unpaid_amount',
      'status',
      'user_id',
      'description'
  ];
```

When I try to insert data I have this error. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts - the `insert` method takes an array of _arrays_, not an array of _objects_.

Comment: @waterloomatt what is the solution in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to do it that way? you can save in the for loop itself.

```
 for ($x = 0; $x <= 12; $x++) {
      Payments::create([
          'id' => Uuid::generate()->string,
          'number_of_months' => $request->number_of_months,
          'status' =>  $request->status,
          'date_of_expire' => $request->date_of_expire,
          'amount' => $request->amount,
          'unpaid_amount' =>  $request->unpaid_amount,
          'user_id' => $request->user_id,
          'date_of_payment' => $date->addMonths(1),
      ]);
  }
```

Don't need to use DB facade to insert in database. I guess you are using `payments` table for `Payments` Model. If not just add below line in your `Payments` Model

```
protected $table = 'payments';
```

Comment: The model was okay, but this method create inside for loop was a great solution

Thank you